# How to access a function in the list?

Tags: r

Assume i have a `list` as below:

```
mylist<-list( c(12,3,12,5),"Hello R",sin  )
```

so, the **third** element of my `mylist` is a **sin(x)** function:

```
mylist[3]
[[1]]
function (x)  .Primitive("sin")
```

***what if i want to pass an element to it?***

For instance i want to get `sin(90)`

I have tried the `mylist[3](90)`:

```
mylist[3](90)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very very close. Notice that when you type `mylist[3]`, next to your desired output, you also get `[[1]]`. This means that this is a list with element 1. You can see this if you do

```
> str(mylist[3])
List of 1
 $ :function (x)
```

To subset the very element of the list (and not just the third list element), you should use double bracket.

```
> mylist[[3]](90)
[1] 0.8939967
```

[Here is a nice representation](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/643381054758363136) of how to work with lists in R.

Alternatively, you could name your elements and access them that way.

```
> mylist <- list(a = c(12,3,12,5), b = "Hello R", allmysins = sin)
> mylist$allmysins(90)
[1] 0.8939967
```